# Android Textview is not showing full typeface of hindi text

Tags: java, android, textview, typeface, android-typeface

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/holo_blue_green"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_question"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:text="………यांच्या मते १८५७  चा  उठाव म्हणजे “भारतीयाचे पहिले स्वातंत्रयुद्ध ” होय ."
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

भारतीयाचे - this word is not full.

Comment: Can you post your full layout file code ?

Comment: yeah i updated the code pls check it @GrIsHu

Comment: Try to use some other hindi font or just remove txtQues.setTypeface(_maratiTypeface);

Comment: We tried with marathi and different hindi questions, it happening same thing. @KapilVats

Comment: Try out by setting `android:maxEms="50dp"` and then check.

Comment: It is not working @GrIsHu

Comment: Make your width to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: again not working @GrIsHu

Comment: Apply the `padding="5dp"` to your textView.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48754/discussion-between-skr-and-grishu)

Answer (score 0):

Change encoding to "windows-1250"

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your text dynamically or you just paste your text in the eclipse text editor and check how the look is showing in that view after it's showing the same view What you have mentioned as above image..You will Do the below steps

Step 1: Paste your TTf file in the Assets  folder and belowed the name Fonts/Verdana.ttf
Step 2: And use your fonts dynamically...like below

```
 TextView myTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textBox);
 Typeface typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/mytruetypefont.ttf");
 myTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
```

All the best